# unable to drop or alter table on postgresql

Tags: alter-table, drop-table, postgres-xl

We recently encountered a problem using the postgres-xl software, there is a table we can not drop can not alter, will always be in the execution state. We checked the Internet, and some answered that the table is locked, but the lifting of the lock Table or can not drop and alter. There are also replied that there is no transaction submitted, we use the sql statement can be found to have not submitted the transaction, but it can not rollback and commit, said the transaction does not exist.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It has been a year since my experiment with Postgres-XL so I do not recall the specifics on the alter restrictions, but in general with MPP databases you generally can not modify the tables ones they are created and up and running.    

The recommendation I got from their support was to rename the existing table, re-create the table with the changes you wanted and then copy the data in to the new table.